# Duplicate mysql table "structure" using PHP only

Tags: php, mysql

I have table called "users" and I want to make an exact copy as "users_2" as regard the structure only not the content.
I wanna do this using PHP only as I don't have an access to phpMyadmin or mysql console.
Do you have an idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After connecting to your database appropriately in php ([mysql_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)):

`mysql_query("create TABLE tablename like SRCTABLE");`

Comment: Solution is correct, but example is wrong. 

It should look like this:
`mysql_query("create table TABLENAME like SRCTABLE");`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SQL `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` command, its result is a `CREATE TABLE` statement in which you can just replace `users` with `users_2` and execute.